# Fail to install nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04. (unmet dependencies)

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

Previsouly, my ubuntu coule not load USB disk, and I tried to sudo apt-get remove nautilus. But that did not fix the USB loading issue, and now I can not install nautilus as well.

When I ran sudo apt-get install nautilus, I got the folliwing error:

```
chenmin@chenmin-XPS9570:~$ sudo apt-get install -f nautilus
[sudo] password for chenmin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus : Depends: libnautilus-extension1a (= 1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 is to be installed
            Depends: nautilus-data (= 1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 is to be installed
            Recommends: gvfs-backends
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to use aptitude as well, but still can not make it:

```
chenmin@chenmin-XPS9570:~$ sudo aptitude install -f nautilus
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gvfs-backends{ab} nautilus{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,124 kB of archives. After unpacking 5,387 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gvfs-backends : Depends: gvfs (= 1.36.1-0ubuntu1) but 1.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
                 Depends: gvfs-daemons (= 1.36.1-0ubuntu1) but 1.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
                 Depends: gvfs-libs (= 1.36.1-0ubuntu1) but 1.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
                 Depends: gvfs-common (= 1.36.1-0ubuntu1) but 1.36.1-0ubuntu1.1 is installed
 nautilus : Depends: libnautilus-extension1a (= 1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 is installed
            Depends: nautilus-data (= 1:3.26.3-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.26.4-0~ubuntu18.04.1 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gvfs-backends [Not Installed]                      
2)     nautilus [Not Installed]                           

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
3)     nautilus recommends gvfs-backends                  



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Please help!

I tried `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade`

Then run `sudo apt-get install nautilus`

Still failed.

Comment: You are facing an X-Y question and made a wrong solution. Now first add the dependencies in your `apt install` command to install all of them.

Comment: X-Y question: the solution for "USB loading issue" is NEVER "remove nautilus", you are doing something irrelavant.

Comment: The unmet dependencies problem is fixed by following this:
https://appuals.com/fix-unmet-dependencies-error-ubuntu/

Comment: OK, the problem of cannot find the USB is also fixed. I did three things:
1. Fix the broken PPAs by following 
[link](https://appuals.com/fix-unmet-dependencies-error-ubuntu)
2. `sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. Enable ubuntu to automatically check for updates
Restart the computer, and the problems are fixed.